# Fakeroot on macOS tries to delete system directories

Tags: osx, c, pacman, programming, fakeroot

I’m having a problem with fakeroot on macOS. I created a `pacman` fork. When I’d like to delete a package, `pacman` tries to delete `/usr/` instead of a subdirectory. On Linux, it is working fine, though.

Error output:

```
~ sudo meme -R but-why
checking dependencies...

Packages (1) but-why-1.0-1

Total Removed Size:  3.75 MiB

:: Do you want to remove these packages? [Y/n] y
:: Processing package changes...
error: cannot remove file '/usr/': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: how are we to know what is wrong with your code when you have not posted the code as part of your question.